# Как измерить потребление памяти функцией С++

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, тестирование, поиск-библиотек

Можно ли и как измерить сколько внешней и внутренней памяти (имеется ввиду место на диске и в оперативной памяти) использовала функция в процессе своего исполнения? Кроссплатформенно.

Comment: Так как эти тесты будут задействовать системные API, это будут уже не юнит тесты.

Comment: @user7860670 ок, тогда просто тесты для каждой функции

Comment: Конкретизируйте, что именно и как вы хотите проверять? Вообще-то, сам факт запуска любой программы из внешней памяти (бинарник ведь там у вас расположен) свидетельствует о работоспособности этих подсистем

Comment: @avp меня не работоспособность интересует, а сколько функция потребила внешней и внутренней памяти

Comment: @avp а "как проверить" и есть мой вопрос

Comment: Может не "проверить", а "померить"?

Comment: Для того чтобы посмотреть кто сколько памяти использует, в линуксе копайте [/proc/](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). ли можно распарсить вывод утилит `free` и `df`. Для винды наверное кто-то еще посоветует. Кроссплатформенность черех #ifdef-ы

Comment: Для измерения потребления памяти [gperftools](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html) выглядит перспективно по крайней мере на линуксе. Из документации не понятно что там с поддержкой windows.

Answer (score 1):

Для отслеживания использования RAM - обратите внимание на кроссплатформенный (кроме windows) инструмент [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org).

А так же оставлю тут [ссылку на другой пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows) с подборкой инструментов альтернатив Valgrind. В том числе кроссплатформенных.

Comment: А как же Винда?

Comment: Действительно, не заметил, что в платформах нет Windows. Добавил ссылку на пост с альтернативами, например, [drmemory](https://github.com/dynamorio/drmemory).

Answer (score -1):

Для измерения потребления памяти [gperftools](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html) выглядит перспективно по крайней мере на линуксе. Из документации не понятно что там с поддержкой windows.

Answer (score -3):

Для того чтобы посмотреть кто сколько памяти использует, в линуксе копайте [/proc/](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). ли можно распарсить вывод утилит `free` и `df`. Для винды наверное кто-то еще посоветует. Кроссплатформенность черех #ifdef-ы